# Rails ActiveRecord::Base remap column names programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Given a table with fields like `title`, `title_sp`, `title_jp`, and knowing a particular language value for a user (like jp), what would be a method by which to remap table fields to model attributes at runtime. Something like setting alias_attribute on a per invocation basis in `find(*args)`.

Something along the lines of:

```
Posts.find(:all, :conditions => {:published => true}, :language => "jp")
```

and have the returned `Posts.title` be populated by the value in `title_jp.` added ideal pointer would also have it able to fall back to `title/title_en` if `title_jp` is nil/empty.

I've been digging around overriding `.find`, but not able to sort out how to bulk remap the field names.

Comment: It looks like the Schema is not well-designed. Are you trying to use an existing schema or the migration was created by you?

Answer (score 0):

It is dangerous to do such thing. You are able to do this with some find_by_sql, but if you persist the object back, you will propably alter the original title, because the model won't know, that it is not the original value.

The better solution is to create a virtual attribute, which selects the best column to return, based on the parameter. It may be a bit problematic to use, but it is much more safer this way. It is not so hard to write a wrapper, so a whole collection can be accessed with a single call, and setting the virtual attribute in each to the right value.

If you have more than one field to override, you can write a small solution to create a virtual attribute to each. If you need more on this, just let me know!